# How to force download files listed and linked, yet open a 404?

Tags: php, html, download

My problem is that I am wanting a personal file storage website to use between different computers, I have little PHP knowledge, yet more in HTML+CSS. I have found how to list files in a directory on a server, that appear to have a link to download. However, if you proceed to click on this list, it loads a 404 error page. Should it not download? How could I make it to force download the file? Also, all files should be able to be downloaded, not just a certain type (e.g .pdf or .jpg). I have looked extensively on this website and others, but haven't found a working solution.

```
     <body>
    <?php
     if ($handle = opendir('./uploads/')) {
       while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
              if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                $thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
              }
           }
      closedir($handle);
      }
    ?>
    <h1>List of files:</h1>
    <ul><?php echo $thelist; ?></ul>
</body>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked the link provided by the script & can you confirm it is correct, read, Can you confirm that one of your domains links there? Is a .htaccess in the folder with the files?

Comment: You need the complete path of the file in the link...It should be something like http://www.yoursite.com/uploads/file.xxx

Comment: $thelist .= '<li><a href="http://website.com/uploads/$file">'.$file.'</a>
This doesn't work...

Comment: Do you have the uploads directory in the website root folder? if not change it accordingly in URL...

Comment: I pretty sure I do, if you mean: root/uploads/file(s).

Answer (score -1):

Much better solution is create FTP server. It is easier managing, faster dw/up

Comment: What do you mean? It is on an FTP server, but I found that it is a clumsy process to upload and download files, being why I created the website to upl/dl files. I have done the upload page and it uploads fine, I am now trying to get it to download through the website.